# Codeigntier/AJAX - Fatal error: Call to undefined function form_input() in

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I was just successful in getting AJAX to get data from the database and have it render to a div that shows upon a button being clicked. But I get this error upon it reading the first line containing php in the view.

Here is my view file html

```
<div id="association-list-wrapper" class="list-wrapper">

        <?php echo form_input('filter', 'Filter by key, name, or location', array('class' => 'text-input filter', 'data-label-value' => 'Filter by key, name, or location')) ?>

        <section class="table-wrapper">

            <table id="association-list" class="filter-results">

                <tbody>

                    <?php foreach ($associations as $association): ?>

                    <tr id="<?php echo key($association)?>" class="result-row">

                        <td class="td col1"><p id=""><?php echo $association['AssociationKey'] ?></p></td>

                        <td class="td col2"><a href="<?php echo base_url('association/'.$association['AssociationKey']) ?>"><?php echo $association['Name'].' '.$association['Title'] ?></a></td>

                        <td class="td col3"><p><?php echo $association['City'].', '.$association['State'] ?></p></td>

                    </tr>

                    <?php endforeach ?>

                </tbody>

            </table>

        </section>

    </div>
```

Here is my JS:

```
$('li#page1').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#pick-list').show();
    $('#association-pick-list').show();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'http://myapp.loc/association/pick-list',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (html) {
          $('#shadowbox').load('http://myapp.loc/application/views/association_management/pick_list.php');
        }
    });
    $('.shadowbox-wrapper').fadeIn(250);
    $('.shadowbox-window').fadeIn(250);
});
```

And here is my controller:

```
public function pick_list()
{
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $data['associations'] = $this->association_model->get_all_associations();

    $this->load->view('association_management/pick_list', $data);
}
```

Why won't it render the page? I tested going to the URL that triggers the controller/method and it renders just fine, but when it renders with AJAX all the php breaks.

Comment: shouldn't controller segment of url be `pick_list` not `pick-list`?

Comment: It's my understanding that the URL value be the url route that corresponds to the controller/function.

Comment: right...and controller function is `pick_list`. Perhaps you have routes configured to adjust?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error occur due to this

```
$('#shadowbox').load('http://myapp.loc/application/views/association_management/pick_list.php');
```

If you load view directly like above then data from Controller are not accessible in view page. So I will suggest you to get data from controller and render on your view.

**Your controller**

```
public function pick_list()
{
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $associations = $this->association_model->get_all_associations();
    echo json_encode(['data'=>$associations]);

}
```

Now render your view with returned data.

Comment: Do I need to change anything in my view?

Comment: you have to render all html content of `pick_list.php`  in your current view

Answer (score 0):

Try this,if you are not getting,please ask,i wil help you

Use this instead of form_input() in view page

```
echo form_open('filter',  array('class' => 'text-input filter', 'data-label-value' => 'Filter by key, name, or location'));
```

In controller ,add this too

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
```

and one mistake in your view form 
associations is the array name you passed from controller. but you foreach is done $association. use $association

Give id to your form and use that id in your ajax
In view

```
 echo form_open('filter',  array('class' => 'text-input filter', 'data-label-value' => 'Filter by key, name, or location','id'=>'myform'));
```

Comment: Getting the same error but this time saying form_open() is undefined.

Comment: am edited my code.add form validation helper too in your controller

Answer (score 0):

are this url right?

> url: 'http://myapp.loc/association/pick-list',

or like this?

> url:'http://myapp.loc/association/pick_list',